# Apache Drill CTAS - Skip invalid records

Tags: apache-drill

I am trying to load large number of files to apache drill database through CSV files via CTAS command.

The query fails completely even if one record in a million is having a wrong value for timestamp.

Is there anyway we can skip invalid records and load the rest in apache drill CTAS command?

Query Used:

> create table RAW_LOADER as select time_report, record_count, TEXT_COL
>   from dfs.`/path/to/csv/`;

Comment: Can you please provide the sql command you are using? My initial thoughts are that you could use the **regexp_matches** UDF to skip invalid records.